# ¿como hacer un INNER JOIN en PostgreSQL que me traiga varios campos y no solo el ID?

Tags: sql, postgresql, ruby-on-rails

Tengo tres tablas

general, ropa, color y quiero traer con un solo query el nombre de las tabla ropa y color según el contenido de la tabla Maestro.

Ajunto imagen para explicarme mejor.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo este query:

```
SELECT g.id, r.nombre, c.nombre
FROM general g
INNER JOIN ropa r ON r.id = g.ropa_id
INNER JOIN color c ON c.id = g.color_id
```

Funciona bien a nivel del sql, pero al adaptarlo a rails:

```
sql = "SELECT g.id, r.nombre ropa, c.nombre color
     FROM public.general AS g
     INNER JOIN public.ropa  AS r ON r.id = g.ropa_id
     INNER JOIN public.color AS c ON c.id = g.color_id"
find_by_sql(sql)
```

Me trae solo los ID, los nombre ropa y color están nil.

¿alguna idea que pueda ser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He probado esto localmente con un modelo `Job` que tiene un `User` y un `Account` asociado:

```
[10] pry(main)> Job.joins(:user, :account).select('jobs.id, users.email, accounts.name')
Job Load (22.9ms)  SELECT jobs.id, users.email, accounts.name FROM "jobs" INNER JOIN "users" ON "users"."id" = "jobs"."user_id" AND "users"."deleted_at" IS NULL INNER JOIN "accounts" ON "accounts"."id" = "jobs"."account_id" AND "accounts"."deleted_at" IS NULL WHERE "jobs"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "jobs"."pending_destroy" IS NULL
+----+--------------------+------------+
| id | email              | name       |
+----+--------------------+------------+
| 8  | erwt@kjkf.com      | kjsgkjdfs  |
| 13 | alter@testingg.com | Developers |
+----+--------------------+------------+
2 rows in set
```

traduciendo esto a tu modelo, debería funcionar con:

```
General.joins(:ropa, :color).select('generals.id, ropas.nombre, colors.nombre')
```

#### Actualizacion

Acabo de darme cuenta que no usas modelos, sino que es un SQL directo. 
Las queries que pusiste no son iguales, la primera sale `SELECT g.id` y en la segunda `SELECT m.id`. ¿has verificado que efectivamente existan datos que se relacionen en las 3 tablas?

Comment: Tu siempre pendiente hasta el último detalle, si existen, error de dedo mio al hacer la pregunta, actualizado en la pregunta esta información nueva y relevante.